# Trigger oncontextmenu event in textarea element Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, textarea

I'm using the packery library for Angularjs from [here](https://github.com/SunGard-Labs/angular-packery). It works fine but I found out that I cannot edit the textarea content when I click on it. After spending some time I was able to make it editable when I right click on the textarea element, but it still doesn't work if I click on it. So now I'm trying to manually trigger the right click event when I click on the textarea so it makes the element editable.

Here's the code

```
<packery ng-model="files" gutter="12" style="border:0px solid black;width:710px;" >

       <packery-object ng-init="user_text='Write something ...';" class="large text sans-font medium-font box-border-raduis">
             <div class="hidden-overflow sans-font medium-font" style="clear: both; border: 0px solid purple; 
                         background: white; border-top: 6px solid #00a2d3; padding: 10px; "> 
                    <textarea id="Mytextarea" contenteditable="true"  style="margin: 0px;" 

                            ng-click="click();"
                            >{{user_text}}
                     </textarea> 
             </div>
       </packery-object>
</packery>
```

and here's the click() function that tries to trigger the oncontextmenu (right click) event:

```
 $scope.click = function(){
          console.log('clicked!');
          var e = angular.element(document.querySelector('#Mytextarea'));
          console.log(e);
          angular.element(e).triggerHandler("oncontextmenu");

        };
```

But this solution doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think a fiddle would really help for those of use very familiar with Angular but less so with packery.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend finding out what is preventing you to focus on the textarea since clicking on it and focusing is the default behaviour, however, you can try to instead of having a div wrapping the textarea use a label where the 'for' attribute is the textarea's id e.g:

```
<label for="Mytextarea" class="hidden-overflow sans-font medium-font" ...>
        Textarea here
</label>
```

I'd usually not accept this since label is an inline element and textarea is a block element but in your case it might help you.

For tracking what is preventing you to focus I'd recommend right click on the textarea > inspect element, and then on the elements tab of Chrome dev tools look for the 'Event Listeners' tab (should be around the right corner of the window) there should be able to see all listeners that have been bound to that element and might help you track the source of the problem.